# Receive FormData as a single Key - Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a Patient like this in AngularJS

```
var Patient = {
        PatientID : $scope.PatientID,
        FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
        LastName: $scope.LastName,
        Disease: $scope.Disease,
        PhoneNo: $scope.PhoneNo
};
```

Angular Controller

```
var pData = new FormData();
pData.append("model", Patient);
var getData = angularService.AddPatient(pData);
```

Angular Service

```
this.AddPatient = function (patientData) {
    var response = $http({
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        method: "post",
        url: "/Student/AddPatient",
        data: patientData,
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return response;
}
```

And my Method in MVC Controller

```
public String AddPatient() {
    var model = Request.Form["model"];
    // this giving me an object instead of JSON String
}
```

Please help me, how do i receive that Patient data, Read and save it in the database, and i dont want to use any loop, i mean like this

```
// I dont want to do this
var patientData = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(Patient, function (value, key) {
            patientData.append(key, value);
        });
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are using this approach.  Why not have your controller action accept a Patient object as a parameter, pass the patient data as a JSON object, and let the model binder do the work?

Comment: you mean like this ? public String AddPatient(PatientModel patient) {
    // play with patient ??
}

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  Just make sure the property names in your JSON match the property names in your C# model.

Comment: Ty it worked but, it's forcing me to use loop var patientData = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(Patient, function (value, key) {
            patientData.append(key, value);
        }); if i dont use this, the parameter in actionresult is null

Comment: You should just be able to specify your Patient object as the data: property of your Ajax call.  Also, I would use "application/json" as the dataType.  That should put the data in the request payload as a JSON object.  If it does not work, look at the request in chrome dev  tools to see the JSON object sent and determine where it did not match expectations.